# Pan and Zoom in Vega-Lite scatterplot

Tags: visualization, vega-lite, vega

I have created a scatter plot that works well, but I need to add zoom and pan functionality to it.

I have searched online for a solution, but I haven't found one that works for my particular case. Can you provide some suggestions or resources that could help me implement zoom and pan functionality in my scatter plot?

Here is my graph and code in [Vega Online Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGgDaoaACc4cWQH1ZSBHDQgA1jWFRVptmV1PFITADuFphWUOZqcMpWao4ATAAMsQDM-In8sQBsfjTKjgCMGbEAnEVJACxlGXkA7AAclRlVeUl+5oHBoWwMsphoYrF5eUoAZkjEbKYind29qPFKppijxFaYbOqC0z19A0MgbUFwIVBdPVaCXmi1lGJitf3V8WJlRfFFA2IjYxNTJzPnlzmCyWY1W6x0WxCFzIVxudweTxebw+SkwcAAHrMQAAlAAqAAIAALwUxOfQ0KA0WQAYQAEgAFVD4gDSlmUVLg+O0pgU+IQrkER05AE82E5KPiAONi-F0GhMJCmQSARkBBIr8QBzsUAQnxWFw+CImEoJwIkiYAEUkDh6YIAgAZACafgYSsc+rwhAIgToaNMJrYCAILjcHi8Pk46kwDAgBAKxVKFSqdQaTRaAF8FCYwhZrLZ7I4QxSw94GL5UYdjuE0VEYugEslUrF0lklDl8oUirVHkUqrFqlV4vEMm9WkdK5C0F2kkUvuNJmjJ6gR+VqsDlmCNkvHnlahkFuOOn8ztCp5Q8kUynk3kk7nuxAPPiBlj9F8eoYDBpQh3VGmI8v0GT9EktTrqCaxbu+AIwqgX4AbUrxXjO7xiIU+7+BiWIAKKmMobCAPiASCyCyyoAF6qkgwqyoK1G0MI+LKHAODmAgpGRHAgrmHqSBOIqRz4pENCirh3QSgAykgMA0PiECWPisicuywnKN0gBkBHq2CekaAYEDAAS0gA6nABnDGJABaYkum66Aeoa3oBL6cD+icQZFu4irhmWkZqDGcadt2bx9gO17DqOmbZuYlg2HYDjoG5JY+H47RHKE1aRNEWINikaSxGI2S5Og8ZFLctTxNUD5lLUyTVEkeRlGOyXHKcsxlLeZRzq+cBLkk1RFDVYErBBELvmgZTJP2B6NZC0Gwj1tT3IkV69RU7wdQuXVQaesHxDcSZJMOYhdi8-ZrvsIKDeCmybZ+O1AbVpVlIdsS1HkmSgRhmKOAAIgAP8REAAG-CoK7L4TQCD4rQTA0AA3HykTCkgqi8nAxCMbyMi8U46iamwUBlmqSpILRrjSSS+KAPqAcDCoxuNOAxknE+yTi8Zg9FsIIyAIGR+JquRCAStK+NOITyoIOptlesapqtfaZTCgAUkwX0XlZgjuppdk+tgTkBq5pPuZ4pZON50axkVJVlRVVU9bV9XhSAZi5tFBZxQbCVlklE45hEtaZYk2XNrl+UdsULyHb1HwvZUdwNd7zVoLutVrb8CewbUSRJOhiwbkNV1pwkBSnQcR7NTNqDVDcr3Js8lTVI915Pi+63TVtRSUC9jQDFUxV1Q0A2bsNZdt5QRSDKVz31M0R2xKimGOAAgrIvGmMTABCrhkj0+KAHqAcBSaY+K0kgEDqApEA0IAmASyLTNZjK4TnSRAP3mMRjHMYgbG09oZ+qBTovc3IgJCm4N8RiQ4sQaSx9ZBiy5JyAA4pYDiYC4BODaI-CWmspY6SYLiAAajAUwGRlDKDKM6JQrp1Y2SwUaByOtnKBmDO7DyxtTa+SKuHPq7x4J1SArUEADsnZRXzLFZwzCjaJQrEeNKfs4gBybOkeqbYCogCKgMZI9QMj3FvGIeI1446lxmInMQ5RZzPm+C3EaqB7hVWLudQe+cjHbUGAOSa8d-gjwyCBUqqF4itWaGUeI71m6pw8Z+PIlAs5Dnmtw561Q7G50uq3cJNxYiVAKNo24XZmhz0+ugNeDAZJIDUGif6chV74icBMJwXMeZkCcqguSaJ6ZU2FLyKppJujdEqWyGgF92T+g0gabBpocDEEkI6eI2IABiCADI0DVhrYZtDHIMP1qGFhEZT4+XNp2dRIFKiZN0fowROZhExULOIzy5Z-DexkRlORjYcpKJAO2QqezG4mPiZeXKz08gGJSlY-aJQU5vjTromqT4c7gSSVYkxGd2r7EPIC4egJrjxG8auB8dR4kvFBRtVFMFrwd3KD1V6e5qjNF3Ii6FF1IKEsTjtBCWcRz-i0UOLs700R5JALiF+LhhRwGvlSfETBClUj9ApTAVJpK02UD9Nigg0RQDgGDUiGMAakQlNeBmLheIyXKcTMgANTA-QpvYemCqGmUEWdQ5Z9lVl6yYRsiRXltlmz8sUAYTwvnLV+S9ARWZHZnLzBct2Lrrle2kXAX2Dz6zyOeSHd5XrEivH-Imd4lVYgAqak4k6p0QlgqcT1Sq2d7F5yXIEzISQ3GGJPICSu7wx6ZEqjVYcvVir4uSUSnaJiaixGekEsezKB4Vuuj2ygK5dxVVegdMe6FuWZWqLqmg+qZCyAqWK1eqhRUMF0BTHQYsbUUOshgGhDr6FOvipst1UZ2F7NTU8C8pi0lVUDRFZ2IjLkRuNlGwF9y6wgCygotJSbVGdhqO8IcFR+yzsaDm7qh0m4WNCdsVAmQAmjthQXPqxRa0orCTBa4u5qgJn7Ho24dUC0oaLfWidNQ3iZv7M8V4Y8sP0sI4yygCZuy2NKFo+EuSsQFLIH9TUcAQFs2kjoIihMd0AwUggeiGpD3mpk4fRGOAiKitJhDKkEBZOKmVDA4irNVRi2VMDYmABVXQBnBD4gXsMfiYlMCrzRJIPp0k1g4DVD0CipgxaYPtdLDgaMxA4FpMQWoAA5Zk8RbVnpC3Qv0V6rmsPdfe4okGEh+LGpShI8HTmRVDa7MRP7JG3OjbGwDwGcrZuUaHeovYcUfDGn3BrSKppWK0a48x85UOzBHI9MtiSONoYyDVJIs8uvuLo7CDOD53gst0f2RFhaCWcdghEjlk3BjtqHLcKF5bsNbbgjUGcQT7jwtw0JxwuIUtOUvsqASpmFyrqKWoTitNeJaeUAF3kiNcKwJU-hZUgW-MvZUojZA-2Ba73BuyBinJCQyFIj4S+YnZIX1kNJJwypT4BYlAAHbaNKsGwWtLeh0ng5kAB5AAsrUeBtRhQICwolyWKzL0uWdcWG9JtMu7Oei8Sb3Y2sDBg++4NJWXaiOva6m53WAP+yeUHTrbzwPPRAoUcolVhwXn6Al-Dua0MDBel2qx159rzDOmNoeTjXqVT2CXAj82K6Tu7PCgchQ9Gdktwy1A7dkhdhKDUdr8TnrsYd+79u-jez9kaMOx6iLF2ODXifYzjmNTKhFnYTP+IADEx91BUSGVT0LBAAAapEyhsHRGZAAkrEAAjigE9VCksV8e2svnhtrlsOFxnPcyQKilR7kb6XQjSvy-S5V5XMaaxxqAwmoO-zGvJpetrgTVVWoIWaAhq3xUzEbaXLb2lDilyG7Ma703H4YKVzuHohCS1Lwp72Kf8daBz8nfG-ftAj+pUu4l4kGFQzwewae6AeIRI0YsgUAMggqpgTIX0TELEX8nIP8REf8ACPMNAGoIqx8gg9M+CAA5LTGKvugwMJAwFqviAADqyAMG0hORkgXz4hQCyYvaIzCjGY7qqCIwwJqaIwMykCYACRKQTAMDw4MEMGAC8G4AKM7+IA6u8zAagUoioqknO562sqWvOCuA+QunqW+GcO+aSIEY8GYQa0+cu36-Oiuf6VYi+6UtWq+6Q6+ryKi8YpUe4L0F4Y0GQl486h+acZQNU62NGm2aGWcU80ejiaGV4D4UKyKd+5c1wlQvyS2P4M4Na-WnU3aXG-4rUjQXiFQbwN4sR+R20k6t4uUrUfiBu5Kd26AKBH8SmTkcCfIrgoosghMHBAkxAF8pE+IP0RB5IN8cAvImBN8SAFMxmxMMAPEfEYh7E-0fSaIEMTgroKkhMEoa8QMNE5gpErgvITA+xnIZIWmbEOmh8EAlOWsOkX0BkCsAQTAsQ9ITAUA8gHeSy3ejqehc+t6OyRhQSWigwPyARLwBQU+IaNh4adhkaUi-6Thsi8aaubhYGXhIJL0Q4WRhQqEwRTifUARAeTiQE7w70F+Y6ac5UARxcyRlR7cu4ARARIEqE-QPyJJ7uX4gU90bKFQ02F4FRX+223GeupQ3h-QzQtwTRIAeCagWBMxOBpExMEAyoww4OlScgDAYhaIEAwgbRkw4xcMAE8QfIsQl8gqlSSM6oAApKBLumaRadJgeqZgTsgLKLJPiDabuCyF9HgviFQWQHukRJZhMBKI6EgAqHAXcSMhwLIF9MMArBAFXtUMQI3nlN8Xar8TzowvoRlnekPliSFLiblFkMVp+mGuVvCb+oiY4TVqroHOiRvlrg9LcJVKEQOlKX4gSRNiyZyS1HcDUEKeCrlNeCbpUdcN4S9PXBnCFBkGNP2eXMSjVGktePrrBlosOWdkyr1ncK8I0LVGmjKcwYfK0tJKcYIGapgCMU5LyEgFAAFtxJMBqBKFztTqaEUKRE4PSMQNZvEGQGwAvFocln8bmQCYLgWcCY9M8PUKRgMLeN2eWecmVnmfPncsicvnVmvhiYUL1L1McnEjOK9LeD2bMLlshgNrRrMDOhSb-jHrMNeAOjkbfpUZXCuMhJnH1IEpNouSPHooEjOi8PybeKNjCn-uXMHtNjOCYrhQ+PxTKfSIqNKvyEccRLiGvAzgzviPAqYAwDgPiLiGwL5kRJgATi9uXvcaaNZlhAwPAmvGILSHkGZNZsBdmboWBRVoCR6vGHhcVHooRc2iRUhTPrYf3jWVVkifWY8o2QMDhf2CAd2HVAOkOIMCYqRYnK9LlP2QAfOftFuWht2EBEkd1oHu3NNnuYlRhn4tKbkZYoHl+GkkhE8FoskH2XbmJfRUuREiBIMF4qUHNHhanvPOgIQbxLyIxMMH6PiNGNGNQeqvJOsOIUJJIUMUpJyGiDAOyGIQZsQK6NpkwHACqpME4IMZxLqDvGwMQPiJpsgDwaKuDjxMZryPUhqHJKumTEgJNdacjjgDGdpKMlhBAAELAKYNSFAL0JmV3lrD3mlp5RBUCT5QlZSmNLlqlZYR+shbPnDQ4alBhS4WiQkHFfEvtPXF2AOBRi4ulagDUeEZRZES1E8P1O1XSvRaNIEn1OOcKcRpNreBeAFL4tRnTZUcSoODYoxiubVAkh1XEf-lURCVRhiheCFBzR9FiCXpRJfDujgBJviNrVTNdTMURERLyK9cQFxAKE5HKpyFJBALJOyIKG-KgYgPJCsUJDRBefUoxC4NNT9BDFMdgUZoAkanABqPyBTPiBzBAGpBZbGQQFAArHThaDADFmwLSI3i3q5dDaBestWVspBT5W2qTYVRTTUNCbLl+nCWFWhdVkvvjY2arM2T5ZdqRr2HuQ+BnJ1ixVYqEcSbVYNmgCBJnC7nRTLaNLVEOJzYHmkQEfvsOsUFVGkrxTdHCIEklR2YdK1MxSPcLbdAVnUInm8EnFysNSAAvMKIFn0Y6AAGvMiY4BlA6hm6UIBwxircTKD4gzHIDYzg7PWWAaicQioLGIymVWYR3Cj5g8SmWmC6gbw3GGre3ykcFg6AIf1w6Ez4iTAcEmb4gAyYB-XvkcBV7wJYQWgBDMgMBmTKBfEgCUI-FZ05k51V1eVZY1SvAt18LFR1DTZl0VkoXgU40+y10NkKIN0eGhysNlT9ilRNr1AkWT2O7NA8V91UVXC6LlD5WzC9ir3yOx6RIHLMklBaJ7ZL1ErdW6Lj7QUvBzQaNdWUA92wbaKcqdwym-TER-Q0CkCmAXxogAMdHmDYwmq+O2CqkOYbVbUCTYA0Bgy45HE6bCDUHw7E646ePeMcSPwf056yAnEAyCCe1yT1LCD6UKiBayDukyCmD4OV5IC4hiBMB6QZBQBlAxaZ1Sww3-Fw2D6eoSOkZ1DIhHRBVWEwkV1VlMNK7oVRWon11FBE3TYLRAS5SFUDovJd0hEvTBIRGVoYoDoaOjSFHn70lc12NAF1RJzh7OPKP01Lm3R+LzO6KHKt1S0s0y1XOUCUrlRpJPAYqUoPAuNO2sTsRcjynTH-yB1kSqDETQw9FOQqrwwGaSAf0qgJO7E5N5Pe2QvqY7oLEGaHy6k4B0CaiqbICiwwLXUvw-SlLTWoK46VM6QKyBKyDxBiRfSkRfTMgtPc7uWMMezw3eW4WzO6K3OLOgbBWwkjPcsCMq7RUiP8KN24XRIZzzqtoHQyuzZ1pDY27ZWoC3B9g7PLhK0zYrNbbXAzn7SQnVQJ45Gf71U7TvBVDPAi7PSXiZw2NbTcmZyVClAcqraXjHl4HQyTAqUf2LC54CQQAuBsFQyyqqqky0FrxyS0yUQkv6baaMRgz6kSjYgMCMAIA0GhvhvSSRvI5ptBumXij4iAAMgPgSpQmznn5gxDS6aAgAEFXmJEwEwHTgZFhMMOyxepy33ty50z5fK0RfOQFHwjw5jaFeK7WbjRMyvmibuHFTPa9PEtiQUGSiq4a-Ee1pq4ea9Lq1nJnMxQc1PZEiAbsOKZkGkjNla9uZEo8DVKw7ePcGYS68vbon4p3NkvvguifcTqMdWyKIbbYI7a0fiM5mqGSNKrjsRIqP9tMcRBJDwcRISLiFYMyIqHYBzGqJ5P0UUlJL5lE1SOQTQIfJh8IQU8zBKBh6vEqJZmRDDA2xwHAMyAyAZHggZGwGJJZJDW+TobrO07ncw8LsuydGu14pSvwiK8M6hZ7DO4I84cI2kKXbK5kH+DVAhHuJVGShmaq27mRQ3Jq9WnULq5PHhnpykVtJXA9KOYPf0L4Texs8KcSruIkPcCOMPncFvfbs866ztJkBYZShiqUCUKUDKVhCAhDOAoIJAkfCGQgLyI6JYODIzIIDRHGyDEJJyBnhTLxDAig9MkcFJPiBGQeofKQMAtJAvEcVcaV+qA-NccINjIpH8+gfiBvLkyKkgK4ExwQJYGwEwAvEkLIHggBT2-x73rJzy1lsUQ+OYVpxnN8xOyFZXdOxFXWUI1K8p9UEuz3IrdNlUJ2A+FTa9KhLTXkVYi1o0Lq9eP1fsyVVtnHqya8HuMq-CiYxlUc4dm8JJ72Lwm+6Y5OokNXPtmNNojKQUkUqvMDI+fyGl0cK9fJJng5v6xg1m9xMIOMRHYICpPhFITQYUuoHpsoKvPTOxNDJzDQOHamxbYMincsRIUTKYNzBTLqPTxE7JDE712vMyAEMMBkDAMkCfON20x5UJ9NyJ3t7VAdxbDt9J5WVNxK3jUp82FCap4dxyple1lo9Mzo2RQESfk52nLeHULRT591PUN2Hr+XI2kOF4o0M0M-odh91UZVDJZHMOJNq2gDwUU-uVKVIffXE+JASAC0SxOBxxDxEcNJFgxZkAlqPTIjN-byMgDoPoHAMMA6c-OYJSMjtcUgEMYjNoCC9gMqBKEvBwfTOugwBqEW1T-YIKiqmW2JFSNpgvGiBTCQVSL13gsgI3tSEQdSF9GwCL9nf2wLoO2hAUJr0swMDr8t6K4r-J5K5MyI62GI8mhr0OhhkReLlTahPXJq3UMVN59LUuJohNBZxOZOkUaLgBNEb1OhLe1yREonh53ogOMVMkD7yKeUCOCCUUWaDFBg+J9WBpqVkAMAd0FPWgHAmZ6oIPSfocGBKFcYf0nAB6CGBJlATRdYu0CMWLyAXhrw147XGYnlzj74gGcREKOofAjLF8OimA-EDFldCc84u+XaiJyGhi9dsQ9QC0HgntD2gsItINlrx20Ki8uWE-QwvGC34IQd+w6UjAvxk78Nl+yvLbqr106a54wSGVCI0CHCS4QuuvK-t3TU6Wsjexaa3FeAPYmJoM1vPzpOlFo1RHeAlYcC71eg397WtJC8Dc1P5PNhasQV5vXFHyNAW6h0MLqrUcDgJiAdEaSHG3-jSRJQQoTiAoAYKQ8eI6AtFkgDBzh1tapgYYBMGQCyBVSMCIYsanRyPx+QBtMrqX2QGoI5AbMIzHyG1KQcVSPENUMhzhhyBRY+IK8LUF66N48gy8BnFAGIDxJ28NDU9Hx1EHj9Fck-XKMVC0H-9dByEeQQr0UHrdZ2m3VfspzUGeE8SHaMaIdEmygkZKVNcqobyFpW5Qij0G7gHxpQnsjW34ffDSVN49RUIH+Ewbo0Oj3hSg6iKxvEh-7txeoCKZbBUHJTf9Qh+STPMRAXg5488yAVUviBjr-UOAFoHAOiGZAxY8ECsZQC3iEGjDO84wsflN2mFLYfk+wgcC9COHy8+G2NJQXOywr8A6ocVW4IzSvDXh96jQeaFTXmhAQj+9wXcLq27CD1rBgIduEOj3CFBdw5jYFM4Nf5BdZyZI9sn1kpKnYX+97HxCuFCL38eoMpCMgzE1KkgMYIdUBMqTyG8FiYmmCiJX21Cj8GGkwgwvnTxK6IKo+2NkVoik6DNy6yw6kasIU4ol529dF5OoIdEYoEU9QeevcEqjHCM4bwIznawtzM1L8ViHjK8CFETpbgeuPROUHMYdpnBvgi4S8FtZIZSoJneMVSTOy+CmgNQa8BeCmz+UIehSEYmSCKS2AlCppHgg5k8bshkBioA6pDBNTyoikgqcYhKGpCXUcgmtTkGID5AnwyQlpHNlgCQC18jg0HCUHTmZ6GZAsKDAQv9l5A18eIu6NULDmMy9cF4sQBWDAC+hV4zIC8C0EBWEEgUbRhIiQUGMHrtkwxMFJYVSPF5K9aRrhBkapxgp-9+gwQ+uNoKpqPAngmrJoIkF1agkyoKYhbM8B6iXg7g8SfbOszOH1UdsDYEoN2BTBrMzeZ-ZzhEnJSLZE8e4PqKhBlIM5XagqNmO0QOogIwYcXUvJrWJjUg7ANAXkMyFJiekKux8M2upmuq55VQ-2cMsJLrbygkYRXIiBgXOIjFry5gBzPyFXgQAEW64qHE5AWKCBeu6IOnPSFiCyQgyAQOnNaL7aPj7RtRBFLcxKAgSRwH4rGl+JpHrC-RIjAMdsNqLVx5opGEbBeFAx682arwjCU4h-zm9u65ggwYHgyD3DEIraWuFokqAu8QphEyKdFLyxe4kwmiGUtAWJAsFyQlIGkAyCZDUTTA2bbSkggcw5dSBKDFAjE2IHCheIDmStiKnUqaUyCnIX6GxChYKRiIeCSIMTFxAmpkuCIghgQDKDTIyADOaZNSGGCyB0QOAUyQJzF6jMiRV4N6OLh8mZp7JU7AXN+Ocl0i-xG-LXCYleDh4UaAEFxO4S3YtQQhz-WYElO8Hd0QhV08uFFPIqB9Ak-hU4Rd0Dz3SExKUt6WPHrh+IAuWUgkDlNJB5SqQdIRkOQM0lSEypCkCqSQPi48wapNAIYhnnqk6AK2+BYiIpUWDgx0ZIqRBIjNhkQyji18WmB1MsAO05IvUndANNfhkxtCOkazGJGmTtsMggQXqAtMm7gUiRl2U6Z2X-CVitpq3HaU5MU4qD6RLQf8UOkqCZwEIXYfsITX8moAkQT-N4bMH2grsLBGKY9g93dxpFlZSVV9NSlvDOCdo0vGoI8DuBeJJGBEh6dazsbzlqq5UcoMGLglgiQAYkekLfWwYKY-ojEYUOjN1B8cdIGQSQNSAVimAB0OAIoDiNoZZl6GZk-mU+NyjyyvE5hZWaRgSyUiHJozXaVLI2Gq8Nc7k-XB8MOHgljuas2krblumjR7Zv00sWhhMTkZ4J1iDuD8M+bPDHogtb6Xe38EIRvJP4VqJkB-7Ep5otUZ6MELHhrkQBPKEmcgmKlkghi6LFBqoCkiCBeQJqUTNeQQAKoxM+8+GHl2JYvZPGDfa2gX3BxHp2u3QYmN1xoiowAGgbOVJJFcADJdihSWSM5gqbDTK8zIEngZAizTIxAMWbtneLcqLSxBUw9ORXK7BVz-Cx3fOdtPsKSzfR+0suaHHgWW8gIK4O4Ms1uFoZXO0Ei5lfmFnNzlRDFVev0A7n-DlZPVLoQxmMFBSVRlKG3BCnZF3hHmf0s7BEgWhZoqoARACEBFOgh8kmHjJyKk18Y0FIG2maNspU5A6B3SK8IzNg0HE5B8mmqRiMRBeqkdXA9gHHOeVQTxNJC8ODeEMQviIx7MutJSg-EPgcxMOTgXrn1GqD2h2+dOMSMoHpC8zYa4vaYTgtLS+Jn29sd0bwwLlrcF8P4hdlguTQdlEqgUcqKxlegndPWmrW7kzSVF-5E4xQDFB3MfzzN3mazUPLVAooDzdG+0Q8mGJKBBI-hLsyUv+Elz-hYKClOxSpQILylhQrE-ENTK6lyQGcjoZkAZSMp+ZTKcI4vJ0vhHhzTQwwMQFwKwAQAW8kgHjriLoatMCRaciyfEqC4tZDoh9bNCgvFloLvRK-Fycp3cKBi0k9nHpiAQlFfITupSlheUtmA0lWo-I7sL2DoVHNSihRTRLxmlGik5oz+NqMOEv5ZLOqrrbqpeECjzQU0ZJbUdaAtF7iqenEQFoMiS6GlOQ9SaVJME5jkhIYDSLeAaifq6AfA6DbkOGQVSChzUiAdGQSv8b5MnIr1EWKULpUUr-5OkbruiGqAt4q8uIbELSHViQKU50C20fmQRqFBHocSeKiyOuw9QxZYrCWScuUElz6RFy8uf+CzhtzpGfUHqDtzVmBIQImrcOLUpLFUK+gbUbOEQtlrXBKldzAEeLi4aWyO4bwGJJRjJLNoJ5TKWFb2B6hARuKGcGUnkE+zbVDUu6bdMTAoIMAD0KoAWL4sE7LS4Fmqu6IOhsl6qFVS-ZVdEvrrqrsFrUGcqIsejP4EIJ3CTukoOiULslsEAdFbwilbZK4gSUFYzUfaDALZZC4UsHimznTKUzQcqKRjqVXhOwD7Jkn2pmwh8M8BQ7PLngPEF5C8O8Tgq6FGAcrTQggDINZlpC0gGcMWekKYBhDCr1lD4zZRKsaolp7wQfYtdM0OWKrjlUSvab+NzVxLVpSzGokyKCJqzcoqERzqwoYrzNk4ZqqtR4N6gGy5sstFzpVBHwAQAuBQTWd+qXK+CKM4tR9loyyr-qIVn4XwfBDfymIAiNa4+jygkj45iIYoPdB0N+xqBbqT1IpIRuHGjj36qpFSaaIJWyB-6rK1SmjxgBFJ8IKoMHPiGVK0dexuEH6BKBJksaA26MxSIzDpi8bMOvXMgLEHRCkQCkOAeBFAFlmrLk5B61OR0zgVPqzCQE3REESvWZrb1xcs5arwfVa5SiMcAzQOEpTsoqaS0c7nVWLShFTV4K0etTXmhVQO5tqllDbkKpkpQizqlPKRhgrCLFZXqm4C1TFEUSfEe4GUjvERxRt8QgAHAIF4EAEpviEK6Qdo+gAXAIrSCALTLIGsXGYXsCoEvizwlBYRMeOiglQ7UpYtJqY3EWEUcBOJsBw6epLwOuPGp-RhCwgRiJMF43g5tA2k5dRwFpDTJrMeQAIHkCwhlAtM8apaQOx003NX1tmjJHnIAC6mYEACcFkDDAaAMELQDQDgABA0AoAPbdBwYBdAIA8yZQPQFGgT1dtNQqkNdpjDMFDtWAAekOB21IB0QfSc7SADICTACobmPQOmB23wBPt2s3REoAcj3aYAVwJ7UgG1JsBBisUUAJgGFDa1HAB23oDtrcyUCchzPIwKAByE48jAda+bB9x96balAwvVAIYH8DY6HASgEbXoBADbag0B2pVE5EcCqBowAsLHdrXxDagAAvPiBIK3ToIJBaXBwUED4w1QaIRwFHSYCnxDSZAAABQC6pClARdLyHmD4hyoAASnxAABqSXZQCt2y76dBgdAIuisAQAYAEwfHXTpAAtC+djO0AMgFJCA7hdoiSkKYCgCCg-APOkGGgDB0TFHY4m4xDtssAnB2QsgI7SAHRCA6DtHEFRCZtkSogWdjgdYjgAmA6AkodAEPc0QiB+BymWIE+CqhvhUgYQO24UGnpO0U70A7O1nczpx3oAW8DAEynQDUCSLi9dE+7JdFewUB6k9gbYDtpOAXBTATejPXntz057O9IAWQIGFb5Cr-AJe0RBXvl0Y6VAgYbrvIEZ1U7-8tOhYERHqSU7gduYMcLkC53u7yAbIQHWqAOqCAsIc02fegGAAkFnp0IEgkyBILYhkiJBXkD-u3rjp-9ku6ZGMDN14gSC6YQwDroFgv6OIm2gRATrYAcxpU80zQM+Gb2Z7MIju53YsCSi570Aq+-kLYHViQ7zA3bXA+npb2rKl9oiCg+vvQPphttQAA) with some dummy data.

Comment: Was your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

There is a pan and zoom example you can look at here: https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/selection.html#interval